# What to plug in first to usb charger when charging: wall outlet or cell phone and why?

Tags: power, batteries

When I charge me cell phone or notebook or whatever what should I plug in first? Should I at first plug in usb charger  to the AC wall outlet and only then to the cell phone or vice versa ? What are the precise physical arguments for this?

I think it is safer to plug in wall outlet first because of peak charge. What is safer for the cell phone circuits?

Thanks in advance.